# Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have this problem

**error**

```
Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ..... line 1.
```

**here is the code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db     = 'catalog';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$adresa_e = $_POST['ADRESAE'];
$nr_matricol = $_POST['NR_MATRICOL'];

$sql = "UPDATE elevi ".
      "SET ADRESAE = $adresa_e ".
      "WHERE NR_MATRICOL = $nr_matricol" ;

mysql_select_db('catalog');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
 die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td width="100">ADRESA ELEV</td>
      <td><input name="ADRESAE" type="text" id="ADRESAE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100">NR MATRICOL</td>
      <td><input name="NR_MATRICOL" type="text" id="NR_MATRICOL"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100"></td>
      <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a log to see what is the exact query that gets sent to the server. Post that query here. . .

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). If you copied this code from a tutorial, stop using that tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are treated like simple text in your request :

Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE elevi SET ADRESAE = '".$adresa_e."' WHERE NR_MATRICOL = '".$nr_matricol."'" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sql = "UPDATE elevi ".
      "SET ADRESAE = $adresa_e ".
      "WHERE NR_MATRICOL = $nr_matricol" ;
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE elevi SET ADRESAE = '$adresa_e' WHERE NR_MATRICOL = '$nr_matricol'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Change this code to:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($db);
```

The Code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE elevi ".
      "SET ADRESAE = $adresa_e ".
      "WHERE NR_MATRICOL = $nr_matricol" ;
```

Change this code to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE elevi ".
      "SET ADRESAE = '$adresa_e' ".
      "WHERE NR_MATRICOL = '$nr_matricol'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the below instead

```
"UPDATE elevi SET ADRESAE = '$adresa_e' WHERE NR_MATRICOL = '$nr_matricol'" ;
```

As you are using mysql_connect remember to escape your strings, from you code I could have your site and get a list of your users.

mysql_real_escape_string

On a side note standard mysql_connect is reaching the end of its life (turn on strict PHP to  see all the warnings about this) use either mysqli or PDO.

A helpfull example can be found [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: i don't need to use this mysql_real_escape_string , because is an example , isn't so important, but thanks